# Accidentally asked the same question twice

Tags: support, status-completed, questions

I'm new and asked my first question on stackoverflow today. I got a error in my browser when I posted the question, so thought the question wasn't posted. I posted it again (after the 20 minute timeout) and then I realized it was posted twice. Can I merge the two questions? I already have answers on both.

[Providing dynamic data to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606869/providing-dynamic-data-to-webpage)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606692/providing-dynamic-data-to-webpage

Comment: You can't merge them, moderators can. Wait here till a mod arrives or flag one of your questions for moderation attention and explain your issue.

Comment: I went ahead and merged them together for you. Thanks for pointing it out.  @Ladybug is right though, in the future you can just flag the duplicate for moderator attention and provide a link to the original.

Comment: +1 for the effort you took to report it here.

Comment: Fixed. Wow, I'm really impressed

Comment: Just curious, what was the error message you received? I see duplicate posts from new users every now and then, so I'm just wondering if there might be some deeper problem that frequent users don't see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a status-completed question that is still listed as [unanswered] because it was dealt with in the question's comments.  Does it make sense for someone to just accept this answer (or someone else's), to clear it from the unanswered list?